# asynchronous output without disturbing the current input prompt

Tags: java, command-line

I'm using a TimerTask to simulate a part of a program which runs in a thread, producing output at unpredictable times.

```
package consoletest;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ConsoleTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        TimerTask tt = new TimerTask(){
            public void run() {
                System.out.print("\n***");
            }
        };

        new Timer(true).schedule(tt, 2000);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("enter a command: ");
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
    }
}
```

My issue is that if you're actively typing when the output occurs, the output is inserted at the current cursor location, and then the cursor is then placed at the end of the output string.

For example, here's a screenshot of me slowly typing 12345678, you can see the output gets inserted in the middle of my typing.

[image: command line demo of problem]

I don't want this asynchronous output to disturb the current input cursor so severely. If I could print the output after the location of the cursor without changing the cursor position, that would be fine. Or even better would be to print the output before the current prompt altogether(moving the prompt downwards), but I think that would probably involved somehow ending the prompt, printing output, and then making a new prompt with any input in progress copied over.

Comment: What you mean is i think, when you're typing the "***" is behind the cursor?
So when you type: 1*** 12*** 123*** etc.???? Please post some additional information. Thanks.

Comment: @bitwave, yes if it could be accomplished like that(the cursor never changes position, and further typing pushes the *** away) that would be excellent.

Comment: @rambocoder it is *very* uncommon to do something like that. command-line applications are normally designed to only accept parameters which then tell them what to do.

Comment: @LukasKnuth, ya I haven't personally noticed many do this either.

Comment: @rambocoder I have noticed none, that's why I think it's not even possible (in a sane way).

Answer (score 0):

You have to use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String input = "";
        char c = (char) System.in.read();
        while(c!=-1){
              c = System.in.read();
              input += c;
              System.out.print("\r"+input+"***"); // \r returns the cursor to the line-beginning
        }

        //extra stuff
}
```

This is maybe what you want. Sorry for possible wrong Java-code i write this from my mind...

Comment: the nextLine() blocks until the enter key is pressed. This cannot help the situation.

Comment: I think you don't have to use a Scanner, you should read from System.in every single char...

Comment: hmmm.... I think this latest idea of yours could work ok, so long as I can do non blocking reads on System.in

Comment: when you use I/O with threads in an asynchronous way, you should use [this](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/concurrency/)